# displaying a picture from a folder using a product name as a variable in actionscript

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Hi I have a popup that displays a product details and I would like to display a picture from a folder which is named same as the product - so for example:

```
...
imageName  = "pca" + this._product.productID;
...
```

My question is how can I display an image using imageName + .jpeg

Doing this works but I need to be able to substitute the image name by a variable - dynamically:

```
    <mx:Image name="testImg" width="100%" height="100%" source="file:///C|/MultimediaSync/pictures/pca98694E000.jpg">
    </mx:Image>
```

What I want to do instead is something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<mx:Image name="testImg" width="100%" height="100%" source="file:///C|/MultimediaSync/pictures/&imageName">
    </mx:Image>
```

I am stuck on the syntaxt do this here...might be a simple one but I am a novice to as3/Flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your `imageName` as [**Bindable**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html):

```
[Bindable]
private var imageName:String;
```

and then use curly brackets`{}` in the source:

```
<mx:Image name="testImg" width="100%" height="100%" 
    source="file:///C|/MultimediaSync/pictures/{imageName}">
</mx:Image>
```

Whenever you will change `imageName` variable, the `source` will be updated respectively.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately:   my code as below - funny that  trace(imageName); returns the image name in the console and hard coding the image name works too
    <mx:Image name="testImg" width="100%" height="100%" source="file:///C|/STSMultimediaSync/market/pictures/{imageName}">
  </mx:Image>

Comment: @user421658 It should work. Make sure that your path is correct.Maybe you have forgotten to add `.jpg` extension?

Comment: yes - it should work and it does NOW!! I didn't realise not all products have pictures in the folder - cheers ;)

Comment: I would like to check if the file exists and if not display noimage.gif.  The below is returning false in the console, can you help?                   var fileName:File = new File()
    fileName.nativePath =      "C:/STSMultimediaSync/market/pictures/{imageName}";
    trace(fileName.exists);

Comment: @user421658 Create a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

First define a class binding the image you need. Then the bitmap of the image can be retrieved, encoded (using an encoder) and assigned to the source property of mx.controls.Image instance.

After the formation of the image, it can be added to a canvas as a child. Alternatively, it should work if the source attribute is bound to the encoded data obtained from the class instance. I had the same problem and first solution worked for me. Following is my reference.

http://shyarmal.blogspot.com/2012/12/flex-displayable-image-from-image.html

Answer (score 1):

If Your Variable have Full Path Of Image, then You have To assign a Id to Image Like

```
<mx:Image **id="testImage"** name="testImg" width="100%" height="100%" source="file:///C|/MultimediaSync/pictures/&imageName">
</mx:Image>
```

[1] You can Assign A Image Like

```
testImage.Source=imageName;
```

and call every time when your imageName variable chagen.

[2]  make sure your variable must be a `[Binadable]`.
as per Above answer.

Hope Your Problem'll be solved...